# Deserializing CSV with Jackson that might have lines enclosed with double quotes

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

Suppose I have a CSV file that looks like this

```
firstName,lastName,address
"John,Doe,"Imaginary St. 42, 1234 Hometown""
Jane,Doe,"Castle St. 1, 5678 Littletown"
```

how would I be able to deserialize rows into a objects of the following class

```java
public class PersonRecord {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String address;
}
```

using `jackson-dataformat-csv`?

Main challenge here is that lines *might* be completely enclosed by double quotes which should be ignored, however double-quotes should still be allowed to enclose `address` values in this case.

The naive solution would be to create a temporary file and strip the first and last character of each line that starts with double quotes. It looks like I can make the assumption that the first column will never be enclosed by quotes so it seems safe to take this shortcut.

However is there a smarter solution to this problem not requiring temporary files?
So far I haven't been able to hook into the tokenization process and "update" the object tree for problematic likes so regular object tree processing can continue in a custom `JsonDeserializer`.

Comment: So what you're saying is "I have a document that looks somewhat like CSV, but isn't". The best solution is to make whoever's delivering it deliver valid CSV instead. If that fails, you could try removing the quotes from each line if it both starts and ends with a quote, but then you may run into issues if both first name and address are quoted. Or you could try to detect lines ending with two quotes, but that'll only work if the address is always quoted.

Comment: Agree with previous comment regarding insisting on a valid CSV format. What you are calling the naive solution is simply a custom solution to deal with a customized file that is not valid for anyone else in the world. Customization in this area is (generally) bad, and a smarter solution may not exist. (Now, one thing that could be better than a temp file is manipulating the data in-memory, but that also depends on file size and whatever other limitations you may have in your environment.)